# Javascript change event for html.dropdownlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I am beginner on **javascript**.

I try to use **Html.Dropdownlist** in Asp.net Mvc.

I have 1 dropdownlist and other 4 dropdownlists.

If 1.dropdownlist change value , i want to apply 1.dropdownlist value for 4 dropdownlists by using foreach in javascript.

**Html:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("MainDropDownList", listItems, "Select", new { @id = "MainDropDownListID" }) 

// İf this dropdownlist value changes , i want to apply value to other dropdownlists.

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("MyDropDownList1", listItems)</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("MyDropDownList2", listItems)</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("MyDropDownList3", listItems)</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("MyDropDownList4", listItems)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
  $(function () {
        $('select#MainDropDownListID').change(function () {
            var SelectedValue = $(this).val();

         //How can i apply selectedvalue to 4 dropdownlists value using foreach ?

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `.val()` function can also be used to [set a value by supplying the value as an argument](http://jsfiddle.net/X8T66/):

```
$('#MainDropDownListID').change(function () {
    var SelectedValue = $(this).val();
    $('table select').val(SelectedValue);
});
```

Comment: i will accept your code as the best answer.Thanks for help.I would like to learn one more something. If my table id is "MyTableID" , how would code be . How can i use table id in stead of "table select" ?

Comment: @user3409638: You can specify the `id` in the selector as well, such as `#MyTableID select`.  Separating selector elements by a space simply means that the latter elements are descendants of the former elements.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you would need to access the dropdown correctly - #MainDropDownListID for ID

Then just set the value

```
$(function () {
    $('#MainDropDownListID').change(function () {
        var SelectedValue = $(this).val();
        $('#MainDropDownList1").val(SelectedValue);
        $('#MainDropDownList2").val(SelectedValue);
        $('#MainDropDownList3").val(SelectedValue);
        $('#MainDropDownList4").val(SelectedValue);
    });
});
```

or in one go

```
$('select[id^"MainDropDownList"]').val(SelectedValue);
```

Or using each:

```
$("table").find('select[id^"MainDropDownList"]').each(function() { 
 $(this).val(SelectedValue);
});
```

Comment: how can i do this by using foreach ? i do not want to set one by one.

Answer (score 0):

**Assign an unique id to each dropdown and do as below:**

```
<td>@Html.DropDownList("MyDropDownList1", listItems,new {id="ddl1"})</td>

     $("#ddl").change(function()
    {
       var SelectedValue = $(this).val();

    });
```